# Accessing an Image from Data Template in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a page constructed, where I need to access an Image from Data Template. The image name is image_3.

My xaml is constructed as such (just an idea of datatemplate):

```html
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary x:Name="ResourceDictionary">
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomKey">
          <Grid>
            <StackLayout>
              <Image
                x:Name="ImageToBeChanged"/>
              <Button Clicked="BtnClicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Now, everything works and displays correctly, but in the method

BtnClicked() I want to dynamically set Source of ImageToBeChanged and I cannot access ImageToBeChanged in C# layer.

Thank you for all ideas!

Comment: you can't access templated items by name.  If you need to modify an item in a template you should do it by data binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jason said, you could use the data binding.

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Name="ResourceDictionary">
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomKey">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image x:Name="ImageToBeChanged" Source="{Binding image}" />
                        <Button Clicked="BtnClicked" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>

            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <!--  Place new controls here  -->
        <ListView
            x:Name="listView"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomKey}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding images}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<Info> images { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        images = new List<Info>()
        {
           new Info(){ image="pink.jpg" },new Info(){ image="pink.jpg" },new Info(){ image="pink.jpg" },new Info(){ image="pink.jpg" }
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void BtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
public class Info
{
    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up creating a two-way binding with a template class to hold all the data entries etc. What I wanted to achieve is parallax screen effect for SignUp process for my App, it looks quite amazing with grid with a scrollview image background and carousel view on top of it. Carousel's pages are different for each entry, therefore the issue becomes accessing the data from DataTemplate. Thank you all for help!